# Strange counting behaviour when sorting list of tuples into dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tuples

I've been looking at this problem for hours and I can't figure my mistake out. Here's the Python code (where raw is a list of tuples like [(2.0,'w'),(2.2,'WSW'),(4.5,'N')...]. The first tuple element is a float representing the windspeed. The second is a string for wind direction.

```
bands = {'<0.5':[],'0.5-2':[],'2-4':[],'4-6':[],'6-8':[],'8-10':[],'10+':[]}
counts = {'<0.5':0,'0.5-2':0,'2-4':0,'4-6':0,'6-8':0,'8-10':0,'10+':0}
cardinals = {}
cardinal_count = {}
for item in raw:
  if not cardinals.has_key(item[1]):#wdir e.g. 'W'
    cardinals[item[1]] = bands
for item in cardinals.keys():
  if not cardinal_count.has_key(item):
    cardinal_count[item] = counts #

for speed,wdir in raw[:10]: # raw is very long - use only first ten for illustration
  target = cardinals[wdir]
  if speed < 0.5:
    cardinal_count[wdir]['<0.5'] += 1
  elif ((speed >= 0.5) and (speed < 2.0)):
    cardinal_count[wdir]['0.5-2'] += 1
  elif ((speed >= 2.0) and (speed < 4.0)):
    cardinal_count[wdir]['2-4'] += 1
  elif ((speed >= 4.0) and (speed < 6.0)):
    cardinal_count[wdir]['4-6'] += 1
  elif ((speed >= 6.0) and (speed < 8.0)):
    cardinal_count[wdir]['6-8'] += 1
  elif ((speed >= 8.0) and (speed < 10.0)):
    cardinal_count[wdir]['8-10'] += 1
  else:
    cardinal_count[wdir]['10+'] += 1
print cardinal_count
print raw[:10]
```

I would have expected that summing up all of the integers in all of the bands declared in the dictionary cardinal_count ('<0.5','0.5-2' etc) would give me not more than the slice of the 'raw' list (in this case `raw[:10]`). As you can see from the output below (sorry for the formatting), *far* too many increments have occurred. Even the first entry ('E') has 7 increments for band '2-4' and 3 increments for '4-6' - that's ten right there. I must be looping over way too many things, but I thought the `for x,y in [tuple...]` syntax did exactly that?

```
cfarrell@x201:~> python test.py
{'E': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0,'0.5-2': 0},
 'ENE': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'WSW': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'S': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'SSW': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'SW': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'NE': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'ESE': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}, 
'WNW': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0},
'W': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0},
'SSE': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0},
'SE': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0},
'NW': {'10+': 0, '2-4': 7, '4-6': 3, '<0.5': 0, '8-10': 0, '6-8': 0, '0.5-2': 0}}

[(4.45, 'SSW'), (4.45, 'SSW'), (2.51, 'S'), (2.99, 'SSE'), (3.16, 'SSW'), 
 (3.97, 'S'), (2.39, 'WSW'), (3.03, 'S'), (4.18, 'S'), (2.99, 'S')]
```

Comment: can you simplify your question? Enclose sample data (like 5 elements or so), your output and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in raw:
  if not cardinals.has_key(item[1]):#wdir e.g. 'W'
    cardinals[item[1]] = bands
for item in cardinals.keys():
  if not cardinal_count.has_key(item):
    cardinal_count[item] = counts #
```

You have reference duplication issues here. When you assign `bands` to the many different `cardinals[items[1]]`, they all get the exact same bands dictionary; incrementing one of them will increment all the others. Same for `counts`. You should provide a copy of each dict, instead of the original dict.

```
#at the top of your script:
from copy import deepcopy

#meanwhile, several lines down...
for item in raw:
  if not cardinals.has_key(item[1]):#wdir e.g. 'W'
    cardinals[item[1]] = deepcopy(bands)
for item in cardinals.keys():
  if not cardinal_count.has_key(item):
    cardinal_count[item] = deepcopy(counts) #
```